# Multiple Images/ Slider with custom post [single.php]

Tags: customization, codex

I am looking for a approach to add multiple images option under the Feature image section in wordPress custom post type. I will integrate/implement these images on `single.php` file where I want to show the slider images.
I want to do it using `Codex` / coding approach, Please **NO PLUGIN**.
Any Idea/help will be appreciated.